# Sum 2 fields in Django admin screen?

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

My model.py:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    fee = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    # total is price + fee
    total = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My admin.py

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields=[]
    list_filter=[]
admin.site.register(MyClass,MyClassAdmin)
```

In the Myclass Admin screen, when the user type the price field and the fee field, the total field would be updated.

What is the best practice to do this? Using javascript?

Comment: Yes you can do it by using javascript in client side and just check total value before saving it in admin.

Comment: if you are not storing this sum, use javascript. If not, you should use signals to make the math.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a realtime display in your interface you have absolutely to use javascript(jquery) and update the total on update. But in order to save it in the database use the save method of django models as follow:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    # attribute here ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.total = self.price + self.fee
       super(MyClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it will be nice if someone can do this with javascript in the admin change list view